# Get value of sharepoint 2007 Author (created by) field

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I am trying to set up a pass-through URL filter so that our Announcements page can be viewed showing results from just one person.

I am looking to build a URL as follows:

```
http://teamspace.intranet.group/sites/XXX/Lists/Announcements/AllItems.aspx?
&FieldName1=Author
&FieldValue1=????????
```

I am struggling to find the appropriate VALUE to place in the URL.  Have tried domain/userid, the active directory user name / description, "firstname lastname", "lastname,firstname" (all with case sensitivity and url encoding)  to no avail!

I do not have infopath or any web development products / special sharepoint connectivity.  **How  can I figure out the value of the internal Author field for a particular user?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming this is SharePoint 2010, when you use the filter you need to pass:

?View=**VIEWID**&FilterField1=Author&FilterValue1=**FULLNAME**

You can see your full name by going to http://site/_layouts/userdisp.aspx?Force=True on the **Name** field.

You can get the view ID by going to it's settings.

The strange part is that you get all that navigating the filter UI.

EDIT:

Found an open 2007 site on the web, here:

https://portal.wusm.wustl.edu/mscits/tipjar/Lists/Team%20Discussion/AllItems.aspx?View=**{4534CB53-DB3F-46C3-8C8E-D6449EF15201}**&FilterField1=Author&FilterValue1=**Capkovic%2C%20Kathy%20%28MSCITS%29**

The Capkovic%2C%20Kathy%20%28MSCITS%29 parameter is really just a URL encoded value for **Capkovic, Kathy (MSCITS)**, you can decode it with javascript as in:

`decodeURIComponent("Capkovic%2C%20Kathy%20%28MSCITS%29")`

Comment: It is sharepoint 2007 (have edited my question). There wasn't a FullName field when I appended the URL above (I got my own details), and the 'regional settings' did not show a user id..

Comment: I mean the full display name of the user, like FilterValue1=Joe RawFocus

Comment: It does, I did test it after you mentioned? Not sure what you are doing wrong, maybe not passing the viewId, you understand the bolded values in the sample URL are variables that you have to fill with your specific information right? See EDIT above.

Comment: It was the VIEWID I could not get hold of - not sure what you meant by going to (it's settings) ?  Anyways - have figured it out how to do it now, you can just create a manual filter (by clicking on the column heading) then copy the URL (which then contains the VIEWID).  Accepted.  Thanks!